# Base url in Mojolicious template rendering

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Is there a way to have urls such as `/foo/bar` replaced bay `baseurl/foo/bar` for each template rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. You can do this with the [`before_dispatch`](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious#before_dispatch) hook (or maybe the `before_routes` hook) in the `Mojolicious::App` object.

```
app->hook( before_dispatch => sub {
        my $c = shift;
        unless ($c->req->url->path->to_route =~ m#/baseurl#) {
            $c->req->url->path( "/baseurl" . $c->req->url->path->to_string);
        }
    } );
...
app->start;
```

Comment: Is it really the canonical way to do so? It seems a little bit hacky for such a common feature and broke my backend (although this is my problem)

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments yet but I just wanted to add that mob is correct - the example code using hooks is the recommended approach for URL rewriting:

http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Rewriting